# setting character variants ss01, ss02, ... in vscode settings does not work in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using fira code font and I am setting `"editor.fontLigatures": "'ss01','ss03','ss04','ss07', ..."` in vscode. The character variants are working fine inside the editor but It is not working in terminal. So how to make vscode to show character variants in terminal?

[image]

**OS: Linux (Elementary OS)**

Answer (score 0):

Ligatures are not supported in the terminal yet:  See (and upvote) [Support ligatures in terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34103).

Also, the setting `editor.fontLigatures` will only affect the editors, not the terminal.