# Progress bar in Vs code terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, frontend, windows-terminal

How to change the default progress bar in terminal to fira code's custom progress bar in VS code?
[image: terminal loading bar]

I just installed and applied Firecode Fonts on my vscode terminal. The fonts were applied but I see that the progress bar of my terminal remains the same as it brings by default, any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following the documentation found here: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode?tab=readme-ov-file#editor-compatibility-list => Visual Studio Code - I get to this page: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions which have fine instructions.  Does that solve the problem, @kalpesh ?

Comment: If you are not familiar with editing the settings you can see how here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0o5SADw6UJ0

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69379859/11107541